# jQuery dynamically added text will not load web font style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have a simple web page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script ...></script>
    <link .../>
    <script>
      /* HERE */
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cnt"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the head section I load *jQuery* scripts and *Google Web Fonts* font styles.

I want to dynamically add content to my `#cnt` and I do the following (the code below is placed in the highlighted place in the code listing printed before):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $el1 = $('<div  style=\'position:absolute;top:50px;left:425px;font-family:\'Oxygen\',sans-serif;font-weight:300;font-size:35px\'>Hello1</div>');
  var $el2 = $('<div  style=\'width:350px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:110px;left:425px;font-family:\'Open Sans\',sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:19px\'>Hello2.</div>');
  var $el3 = $('<div  style=\'width:350px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:110px;left:425px;font-family:\'Open Sans\',sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:19px\'>Hello3.</div>');
  var $el4 = $('<div id=\'imm\' style=\'position:absolute;top:-10px;left:-20px;background-image:url(\'images/imm.png\');width:399px;height:503px\'></div>');
  $('#main').append($el1); 
  $('#main').append($el2); 
  $('#main').append($el3); 
  $('#main').append($el4); 
});
```

However once displayed **fonts are not styled as they should be** (meaning that the Google Fonts are not applied, my text is displayed using default settings as if the specified `font-family` didn't work) and **the image is not loaded**.

I am sure this is something common but could not find questions on this matter. What to do?

Comment: Are you sure fonts are really downloaded? You can check it in Web developer tools/Firebug. Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery could help you to do the same in a more readable way (by the way avoiding some headhakes).

```
  var $el3 = $('<div >Hello2.</div>')
                 .css({
                     'width':'350px',
                     'height':'200px',
                     'position':'absolute',
                     'top':'110px',
                     'left':'425px',
                     'font-family':"'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:19px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s because you messed it up with the quotes – you start the value of the `style` attribute with `'`, and then the first `'` of your `font-family` declaration *ends* it again.

Just use double quotes for the value of the `style` attribute – which you can do without any escaping, since the JavaScript text literal is using `'` as delimiters – and then leave the escaped single quotes for the `font-family`:

```
var $el1 = $('<div  style="position:…;font-family:\'Oxygen\',sans-serif;…font-size:35px">Hello1</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its a quotes problem, try

```
  var $el1 = $('<div  style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:425px;font-family:\'Oxygen\',sans-serif;font-weight:300;font-size:35px">Hello1</div>');
  var $el2 = $('<div  style="width:350px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:110px;left:425px;font-family:\'Open Sans\',sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:19px">Hello2.</div>');
  var $el3 = $('<div  style="width:350px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:110px;left:425px;font-family:\'Open Sans\',sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:19px">Hello3.</div>');
  var $el4 = $('<div id=\'imm\' style="position:absolute;top:-10px;left:-20px;background-image:url(\'images/imm.png\');width:399px;height:503px"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are double enclosing single quotes:

```
$('<div style=\'posiblablafont-family:\'Oxygen\',font-size:35px\'>Hello1</div>');
 USE " here ---^                                     AND HERE --^
```